# Passing MultiValue Parameter in MDX

Tags: reporting-services, mdx

How to pass MultiSelect parameter from SSRS to MDX?

I tried as below which is not working as expected:

```
WHERE ({IIF( STRTOSET(@Name, CONSTRAINED).Count = 1,
STRTOSET(@Name, CONSTRAINED), [Name].currentmember )})
```

Comment: What should the MDX be doing ? -> [Name].currentmember is wrong in a where clause

Comment: Then how can we write it in MDX? I want my query to run for all the Names that has been selected in the parameter @Name

Answer (score 0):

You can use directly :

```
WHERE ( STRTOSET(@Name, CONSTRAINED) )
```

or (not sure about this ) :

```
WHERE ( IIF( STRTOSET(@Name, CONSTRAINED).Count = 1, 
         STRTOSET(@Name, CONSTRAINED), 
         STRTOMEMBER(@Name, CONSTRAINED) ) )
```

However SSAS and set slicers are not always good friends. If possible use [MDX Subselects](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/SubQueries.html) instead :

```
WHERE ( SELECT STRTOSET(@Name, CONSTRAINED) ON 0 FROM .. )
```

Comment: Thanks I will try and let you know